# DataTemplate in Silverlight 5 to show list data

Tags: c#, datatemplate, silverlight-5.0

I want to design a data template as silverlight static resource, which help me to show the list of items, say of type `IdentityData`. This class `IdentityData` has two data members- `Title`(string) and `Data`(IDictionary(string as key, object as value)).
Basically, I want to populate list of `IdentityData`, say `IdetifiedObjects` in following format-

### Title1

ID(Key)             1234(Value)

Shape(Key)          Oval(Value)

Department(Key)     Accounts(Value)

Name(Key)           ABC(Value)

### Title2

ID(Key)             5678(Value)

Shape(Key)          Circle(Value)

Department(Key)     Helpdesk(Value)

Name(Key)           XYZ(Value)

Can anybody help me to get the data template to show the data in this format ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Following is the DataTemplate so far I am working with-

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InfoWindowDataTemplate">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
     <Grid x:Name="TitleGrid">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
         <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
         <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <TextBlock x:Name="TxtTitle" Text="{Binding Path = Title}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
     <TextBlock x:Name="TxtLineDivider" Text ="-----------------------------" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1"/>
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Data}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2">
                 <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Data}">
                 <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                   <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Keys}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                   <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Values}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                 </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                 </sdk:DataGrid>
              </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the list of class which want to display in datatemplate is as below

```
public class IdentityData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    private IDictionary<string, object> data;

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.title;
        }

        set
        {
            this.title = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(this,"Title");
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data;
        }

        set
        {
            this.data = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(this,"Data");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**UPDATE :**

Below is how I use the DataTemplate. I am using it for the control that kind of InfoWindow (third party small window control, pop up to display information)  :

```
<e:InfoWindow x:Name="IdentityInfoWindow" Padding="2" CornerRadius="10" 
              Map="{Binding ElementName=Map}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InfoWindowDataTemplate}" 
              Content="{Binding Path= IdetifiedObjects, Mode=TwoWay}" Anchor ="{Binding Path= Anchor}" 
              IsOpen="{Binding = IsIdentityWindowOpen}">
    <e:InfoWindow.Background> 
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.038,1.136" StartPoint="0.015,0.188">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD1DFF2"/> 
        <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0.946"/> 
        </LinearGradientBrush> 
    </e:InfoWindow.Background>
</e:InfoWindow>
```

Comment: nothing special with `DataTemplate`, you can create it the way you create a Page or Window in XAML, put some containers, and controls as usual. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Within the datatemplate, I have added one StackPanel then within StackPanel Grid is added. Grid contain three rows. First row will show Textblock for displaying Title, then second row has divider, third row contains Grid which has two columns, one to display Key and another one to display Values.
However when I debugged the application, it shows only divider of second row instead of repeatative structure as defined in my problem

Comment: please edit your question to include the DataTemplate you have currently and the problem you have with it as stated in the comment above. And include codes for displaying the List where you use the DataTemplate. With that we have a chance to see what was wrong with your codes and possibly provide some suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: Ok. Modifying Q to add code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InfoWindowDataTemplate">
   <Grid x:Name="TitleGrid">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <TextBlock x:Name="TxtTitle" Text="{Binding Path = Title}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="TxtLineDivider" Text ="-----------------------------" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1"/>
         <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Data}">
             <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
               <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Keys}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
               <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Values}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
             </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
         </sdk:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I did is :

- Removed 2 `StackPanels`. In most case when your `StackPanel` or any other container control contains only single control, that means you don't need the container.
- Removed `ItemsControl`. Your `ItemsControl` contains a `DataGrid` when the `DataGrid` it self is enough to display multi row -and multi column- data. You need to choose either to use `ItemsControl` or `DataGrid` in this part.

Note that until this point I only provide some correction to your `DataTemplate` construction. But as you said in comment, you didn't see a *repetitive structure* when trying to debug, then the problem possibly resides in the place where you use the `DataTemplate`. You should use `DataTemplate` as Item Template of a control that can show multiple items such as `ListBox` or the same to be able to see that *repetitive structure*.

Comment: Thanks for refactored code....however, still I am unable to display data. After spending some time on it, I found that 'PropertyChanged' event handler is null. Hence 'NotifyPropertyChanged' doesn't reflect changes due to null handler. Any suggestions...??
One more thing- this datatemplate which I am using for the control is kind of InfoWindow (third party small window control, pop up to display information) whose code is as below-

Comment: `<e:InfoWindow x:Name="IdentityInfoWindow" Padding="2" CornerRadius="10" Map="{Binding ElementName=Map}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InfoWindowDataTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path= IdetifiedObjects, Mode=TwoWay}" Anchor ="{Binding Path= Anchor}" IsOpen="{Binding = IsIdentityWindowOpen}">``<e:InfoWindow.Background>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.038,1.136" StartPoint="0.015,0.188"><GradientStop Color="#FFD1DFF2"/> <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0.946"/> </LinearGradientBrush> </e:InfoWindow.Background></e:InfoWindow>`

Comment: please stop pasting code in comment. It's hard to impossible to read. Please edit your question again and put the code there instead

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the titles at least?

If you are at least there, there's an obvious second problem:

The `DataGridTextColumn`s are bound to collections. The `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` needs to be bound to the collection in question (your dictionary pairs), while the columns get bound *relative to each item in that collection*.

To do that you simply use the singular forms `Key` and `Value`, which are properties of `KeyValuePair<K, V>`.

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
       <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
       <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

One more thing to mention is that any changes to the dictionary after the UI initialized will not be reflected, because `Dictionary<K, V>`s are not observable.

If you don't even see the titles, put a

```
<Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" />
```

somewhere to check whether you at least see the right amount of items.